# Macro (or GUI) continue to work while the Remote Desktop is closed

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, macros

I am running a ***24/7 macro*** which uses image search, movement and mouse click functions. But I wish I could do it without running my computer.

I run this macro on a VPS that I run with an RDP. Everything works normally.

However, when I close my computer, my internet connection goes down, I close the RDP etc ... Then the macro doesn't work anymore.

I researched for very long hours and I saw that effectively closing its RDP, "killed" the GUI.

- So I found lots of solutions, such as modifying the registry to minimize the RDP window, it doesn't work.
- Or do an RDP loop using RDP Wrapper and IP 127.0.0.2 for example, the loop works but when I close the first RDP, in the end everything stops.
- Finally another solution was in fact a BATCH file with a command and the tscon inside allowing to close the RDP connection without killing the graphical interface. but similar it did not work because it changes the size of the screen and therefore the click functions are no longer well proportioned.

So I would like to know if you know of other solutions allowing, I repeat, to run a macro requiring a graphical interface (clicks, image searches), while having closed the RDP?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: RDP uses sessions per user that logs in and may not be suitable for what you are doing. Are you able to connect to the main user session via VNC or other remote desktop tools?

Comment: I've a chromebook so i will check tonight if there is an extension or application for VNC

Answer (score 0):

You can set the initial connection resolution of RDP to the default console resolution and setup your macros, so it will match the resolution when you close it:

```
mstsc /admin /w:1024 /h:768
```